# how to find out which dragged item was dropped

Tags: jquery

what I am trying to do is create a site that drags items into the drop area and once dropped that specific dragged item calls to a function thats slides in another certain div. I can not figure out why I cant get the if ---  else if working. My goal is to have a clean function that sees which item was dragged/dropped and depending on the dropped item I want a  specific "something to happen" such as a page slide in.
here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i;
var banners = ('#banners');
var tryout = ('#try2');
var navItem = [banners, tryout];
var dropItem = (".nav");


// DRAGGABLE 
$(dropItem).draggable({

});

$("#dropArea").droppable({  
    drop: function() {  

        if ("dragged Item " == banners){
            $(".panel").toggle("fast");
                $(this).toggleClass("active")
        }

        else if ("dragged Item " == tryout){
           // and so on...
        }
    }

}); 

});
```

EDIT ADDITION HERE is where I am now example here www.diskrim.com/tryout
    $(dropItem).draggable({

```
});

$("#dropArea").droppable({  
    drop: function(event, ui) {  

        if (ui.draggable = navItem[0]){
            alert("banners");

        }
        else if (ui.draggable = navItem[1]){
            alert("just pop up");

        }
        else{

        }

    }

}); 

});
```

Comment: Inspect the parameters passed into the drop callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [jQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#event-drop)

The `drop` callback takes two parameters: `event` and `ui`.  `ui.draggable` is the item that was dragged onto the droppable area

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I think i did it correct, however I find myself not able to continue with the if ... else if...  i cant get the else if to work. here is the example if you can help. www.diskrim.com/tryout

Comment: @diskrim You are using a single "=" in your statement, with this you are setting the variable, thus the first statement will always evaluate to true. Use "==" for comparison (or "===" for bitwise)!

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks for the input, however I am noticing that my ui.draggable which is dropItem uses a class of .nav .. so I need to compare the div id of that class nav. how do i call a ui draggable attr.("id") correctly .. i am trying this with no luck: 
if ($(this(ui.draggable).attr("id")) == navItem[0]) {
                alert("banners");              
            }

Comment: you should be able to just do `ui.draggable.attr('id')` or possibly `$(ui.draggable).attr('id')`

Comment: ok well still no luck, i will mark as answered because techinically you answered my initial question but if you could help me out I would really appreciate it. I updated my site www.diskrim.com/tryout . it seems after i added this ui.draggable if statement, the items dont actually "drop" in the box anymore. they are still draggable after

Comment: the strings you are storing in your variables to compare to the ids start with a "#". I think you may be confusing selectors with actual values. If you remove the "#" from the strings you are storing in your variables, it should work

Comment: Thank you MrOBrian...Finally I can go on with this project. lol.. Im used to Flash and AS3 so these minor things pass my brain. Thank you for all your help